# import svelte component ommiting .svelte extension

Tags: rollupjs, svelte

Is there any possibility to configure rollup to import svelte components omitting `.svelte` extension ?

```js
import MyComp from "path/MyComp"
```

MyComp file has `.svelte` extension

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can add a resolver to your configuration with `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`:

**rollup.config.js**

```js
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve'); // add this to the other requires

return {
   ... // the usual things like input, output, ...
   plugins: [
       resolve({
          extensions: ['.svelte', '.js']
       }),
       svelte(),
       ... // any other plugin you are running
   ]
};
```

Comment: Also it is possible to use   @rollup/plugin-alias  plugin 


**rollup.config.js**

```javascript

import path from 'path';
const projectRootDir = path.resolve(__dirname);

export default {
plugins: [
alias({ 
            resolve: ['.svelte','.js'],
            entries: [
                {find:'src', replacement:path.resolve(projectRootDir, "src")}
            ],
        })
]} 

```